# Bash standard error redirection

Tags: bash, standard-error

I am trying to verify if the input entered by the user is of a numeric type or non-numeric type. If numeric type then it will do the necessary operations else it will generate an error message of my design (not the standard error generated)

The steps that i have been using is:

1> perform a mathematical operation on the input.
`echo -n "Enter a number : "; read a`

now if the input `a` is of numeric type then the operation is a success else there will be a standard error generated.

`Enter a number : ww`

`expr: non-numeric argument`

The code that I have used in order to redirect the standard error is :

```
tmp=`expr $a / 1` >&2
```

I have also tried rediirecting it to the null file using the code:

```
tmp=`expr $a / 1` > /dev/null
```

But the error is still being displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about regex the input instead?

```
read a
if [[ $a =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
then
  echo this is a number
else
  echo not a number
fi
```

- `^` means start of string
- `$` means end of string
- `[0-9]+` means 1 or more occurances of a number
- `=~` is syntax for
  [Bash regular expression](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns)

Answer (score 5):

you must redirect stderr within internal expression:

```
tmp=`expr $a / 1 2>/dev/null`
```

Answer (score 2):

Both of your examples there are redirecting stdout, not stderr, because there is no qualifier *before* the `>`.

To throw away stderr, you need `2> /dev/null`, because it's file descriptor 2. Also useful are `2>&1`, to merge stderr onto stdout, and `&> file`, shorthand to redirect both stderr and stdout to the same file.

This page explains fairly well: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html